# MySQL, On delete cascade is allowing to delete child table why not on ON Update Cascade will not update child table?

Tags: mysql

Suppose, Parent table **employee** with a column named emp_id having data (1,2,3).

Child table **department** with column's dept_id and emp_id foreign key. ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE

If user update child table emp_id, Mysql will show error
If a user deletes child table emp_id, Mysql will delete why?
both are not having same behavior ????

Answer (score 0):

You can UPDATE child ID to existed in patent table value.
You cannot UPDATE child ID to a new value, which in not existed in patent table value.

You always can DELETE child values, that is on-to-many relation.